# How to show react spinner without having spinner component in render()

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I want to show spinner in react app without writing some code in render() same as i do in android native progress dialog.

Currently i add this line to my render()

```
<Spinner visible={this.state.spinnerVisible} />
```

And change state `spinnerVisible` if i want show or hide spinner.

and this method which is just needed to call in java android from anywhere.

```
public static void showProDialog(Context context, String text) {
    try {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setMessage(text);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.setProgress(0);
        progressDialog.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do something like this? So that i dont need to maintain states everywhere.

Comment: What are you using expo?

Comment: No, i am not using expo

Comment: Sorry, Read the post once again and saw `call in java android from anywhere.` But if you want I can give the solution for expo

Comment: I am not well experienced in react native, so i will not able to convert my project to expo project right now. but i will like to see solution. please post an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simple don't want to maintain states everywhere, you can just let the Spinner maintains it's own state like this:

```
class Spinner extends Component {
  show () {
    this.setState({ visible: true })
  }
  hide () {
    this.setState({ visible: false })
  }
}
```

And add a single `Spinner` at your root view:

```
export const spinner = React.createRef()

class MyApp extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <View>
        {/* your app content */}
        <Spinner ref={spinner} />
      </View>
  }
}
```

If you want to show spinner, just `import { spinner } from './MyApp.js'` and call `spinner.show()`:

Comment: Yes that's better than setting states everywhere. but still i have to include it in every view component. but this sounds better.

Comment: I will check it, and get back to you.

Comment: If what you want is a single global spinner overlay, just add it to the root view once.